# How do search engines treat out-tracked links

Tags: backlinks, googlebot, tracking, click-tracking

Some websites have out tracking / outgoing click tracking so that when you click on a link such as mysite.com on example.com you momentarily get taken to example.com/outgoing/mysite.com which then redirects to mysite.com.

All this does is enable the example.com's owners to see which links people were leaving the site by, by checking the analytics of that outgoing page. But how does this effect back linking, will a search bot be able to recognize this and count is as a normal backlink to mysite.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any form of link to your site being one in a `link, text, or even a redirection` is a technically a back link. Now the question I think your asking is if Google values the redirects back link. The answer is neither no or yes and depends on the redirection type. If the site redirects using a 301 then it would pass as a backlink, so think of a URL shortner these pass juice and are classed as a good back link only when they they redirect using 301.

Some sites that redirect internally then externally use JavaScript or PHP to handle the request, as far as we are lend to believe if its not a 301 then its not good. Load up firebug and watch the header responses when you click the link, or alernatively do a Google Fetch within Google Webmaster Tools and see the headers that way.

Comment: thanks, i had profiled the redirect using httpfox - and it seems to be a 302 redirect, would that be counted as a backlink ?